# Quincy Kit remote symbolication

Tags: ios

I have implemented the server setup (remote symbolication)based on the documentation provided at http://quincykit.net/.
I downloaded a sample crash report(actual crash report) and tried executing symbolicatecrash crashfilename.crash 
but the result i get is the same crash report which is not symbolized.

I have pasted the required .app.dSYM and .app files to the local folder containing the scripts also have run chmod +x symbolicatecrash.pl

Comment: what's your log output?

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure you had the right .dSYM? u'd try 
***dwarfdump -u YOURAPP.dSYM***, 
then compare the uuid with your crashlog.